# Reading stdin in C

Tags: c, stdin

I have some troubles when I am trying to read from `stdin`. What I want to do is to read unknown lines from `stdin` until character `'.'` is introduced. Could you help me with some examples?

Comment: What's the trouble you're having?

Comment: What do you want to happen when the line has an embedded `'.'`, like `"Go. Now!"`?

Comment: Thank you for the answers , but DipSwitch's answer it's all i wanted!

Comment: @pmg Sounds like he's making an STMP listener. Single dot line marks end of data.

Comment: So a line with `"...."` gets "translated" as `"..."` and should not terminate the procedure, right? @Vlasin? ???

Answer (score 4):

Don't read lines ... read characters.

```
int ch;
while (1) {
    ch = getchar();
    if ((ch == EOF) || (ch == '.')) break;
    /* deal with ch */
}
if (ch == '.') {
    /* '.' detected */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this. There are more efficient ways but this would be fine to make a start.

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // declare buffer
    char str[BUFFER_SIZE];

    // read till .
    int idx = 0;
    register int cr;
    do {
          if ((cr = getchar()) == '.' || cr == 0 || cr == EOF)
              break;

          str[idx] = cr;
    } while(++idx != BUFFER_SIZE);

    if (idx != BUFFER_SIZE)
    {
        str[idx] = 0; // 0 terminate string replacing . by end of string
        printf("%s", str); // print the string
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Buffer overflow");
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Other ways can be something like `read(STDIN_FILENO, str, BUFFER_SIZE);` and then parse the buffer.

Comment: -1: still no check for `EOF`, **treating the result of `getchar()` as `char` rather than `int`**, your `switch` is a no-op, you really shouldn't use the user input as the format string for `printf`, there are missing `#include`s, ..., ...

Comment: hmm the switch was bad indeed... using getchar as char instead of int doesn't really matter unless you would work with unicode. Error is -1 == EOF which I didn't know yet because normally it would read 0 on EOF (normal exit) `#include <stdio.h>` seems logical to me...

Comment: `register`?!! Do you really think that will make any difference?

Comment: taking into account that a `getchar()` would use a syscall `read` and the syscall read only uses 4 register there would be 2 more free registers and on an x64 system even 10 so I think yes (on a linux system atleased) :)